# is it possible to include uploaded files into the project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, file-upload

is it possible to include uploaded files into the project ?
(we do n't want do that manually)

mean after publish those files be seen in publish files ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can we get more information? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add them, simply click **'Show all files'** and then right click on them and select **'Include in Project'**.

Then if you want them published with the project right click on the file, go to properties and change **'Copy to Output Directory'** from **'Do no copy'** to **'Copy if newer'** (or **'Copy always'** if you always want it to copy)

Answer (score 1):

1. If you just want to see the files, then with the project selected, click the 'Show all files' icon just above it (2nd from the left), note that this will show ALL files, not just uploaded ones.
2. If you actually want them included in your project then you could possibly edit the .csproj file programmatically, but i'd advise against it.

Both the above solutions assume your uploaded files are within your project directory.